# Drag-drop li tag to move li tag's direction in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, google-chrome-extension

move.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$( function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
    $("#sortable").disableSelection();
} );
</head>
<body>
<ul id="sortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default">
        <div class="divtext">
            <i class="far fa-play-circle" id="one" style="font-size:30px;"></i>
            <div class="divtext0" id="two">"[Code]" </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">
        <div class="divtext">
            <i class="far fa-play-circle" id="one" style="font-size:30px;"></i>
            <div class="divtext0" id="two">"[Code]" </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
</body>
```

this work in html but if I run in chrome-extension it doesn't work.
How can I fix it?

Or can you tell me if if there is any other way to solve it?